# Experiencing an error while creating Pine Script Library function

Tags: tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a new library in Pine Script-v5 with following function signature:

**export TrendMeterBarsColors(float vclose, float vohlc4, float vhlc3, float vOpen) => **

But I keep getting the following error: " The 'vohlc4' argument is not used. All args should be used.",
even though I have used the parameter 'vohlc4' within my function body. Has anyone experienced similar issue?

Full code :
'''

```
// @function returns the colors of Trend Bars (from Trend Meter)
// @param none
// @returns color.red,color.green
export TrendMeterBarsColors(float vclose, float vohlc4, float vhlc3, float vOpen) => 

    
    ShowTrendBar = true
    WTSetups = true
    TMSetups = true
    MSBar1 = "Trend Filter"  
    MSBar2 = "Trend Filter"
    
    
    
    TrendBar1 = "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5"
    
    TrendBar2 = "RSI 13: > or < 50"
    
    TrendBar3 = "RSI 5: > or < 50"
    
    TrendBar4 = "MA Crossover"
    
    TrendBar5 = "MA Crossover"
    
    
    ////////////////Signals - Wave Trend/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    
    // Wave Trend - RSI
    
    RSIMC = ta.rsi(vclose, 14)
    
    // Wave Trend
    
    n1 = 9  //input(9,    "Wave Trend - WT Channel Length")
    n2 = 12  // input(12,   "Wave Trend - WT Average Length")
    esa = ta.ema(vhlc3, n1)
    de = ta.ema(math.abs(vhlc3 - esa), n1)
    ci = (vhlc3 - esa) / (0.015 * de)
    tci = ta.ema(ci, n2)
    wt1 = tci
    wt2 = ta.sma(wt1, 3)
    
    // Wave Trend - Overbought & Oversold lines
    
    obLevel2 = 60  // input( 60,  "Wave Trend - WT Very Overbought")
    obLevel = 50  // input( 50,  "Wave Trend - WT Overbought")
    osLevel = -50  // input(-50,  "Wave Trend - WT Oversold")
    osLevel2 = -60  // input(-60,  "Wave Trend - WT Very Oversold")
    
    // Wave Trend - Conditions
    
    WTCross = ta.cross(wt1, wt2)
    WTCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0
    WTCrossDown = wt2 - wt1 >= 0
    WTOverSold = wt2 <= osLevel2
    WTOverBought = wt2 >= obLevel2
    
    
    // MA Inputs
    
    MA1_Length = 5
    MA1_Type   = "EMA"
    
    MA2_Length = 11
    MA2_Type   = "EMA"
    
    MA3_Length = 13
    MA3_Type   = "EMA"
    
    MA4_Length = 36
    MA4_Type   = "SMA"
    
    
    // MA Calculations
    
    
    MA1 = if MA1_Type == "SMA"
        ta.sma(vclose, MA1_Length)
    else
        ta.ema(vclose, MA1_Length)
    
    
    MA2 = if MA2_Type == "SMA"
        ta.sma(vclose, MA2_Length)
    else
        ta.ema(vclose, MA2_Length)
    
    
    MA3 = if MA3_Type == "SMA"
        ta.sma(vclose, MA3_Length)
    else
        ta.ema(vclose, MA3_Length)
    
    
    MA4 = if MA4_Type == "SMA"
        ta.sma(vclose, MA4_Length)
    else
        ta.ema(vclose, MA4_Length)
    
    
    // MA Crossover Condition
    
    MACrossover1 = MA1 > MA2 ? 1 : 0
    
    MACrossover2 = MA3 > MA4 ? 1 : 0
    
    // MA Direction Condition
    
    MA1Direction = MA1 > MA1[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA2Direction = MA2 > MA2[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA3Direction = MA3 > MA3[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA4Direction = MA4 > MA4[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    // MA Direction Change Condition
    
    MA1PositiveDirectionChange = MA1Direction and not MA1Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA2PositiveDirectionChange = MA2Direction and not MA2Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA3PositiveDirectionChange = MA3Direction and not MA3Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA4PositiveDirectionChange = MA4Direction and not MA4Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    
    MA1NegativeDirectionChange = not MA1Direction and MA1Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA2NegativeDirectionChange = not MA2Direction and MA2Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA3NegativeDirectionChange = not MA3Direction and MA3Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    MA4NegativeDirectionChange = not MA4Direction and MA4Direction[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    
    // MACD and MOM & DAD - Top Dog Trading
    
    // Standard MACD Calculations
    
    MACDfastMA = 12
    MACDslowMA = 26
    MACDsignalSmooth = 9
    
    
    MACDLine = ta.ema(vclose, MACDfastMA) - ta.ema(vclose, MACDslowMA)
    
    SignalLine = ta.ema(MACDLine, MACDsignalSmooth)
    
    MACDHistogram = MACDLine - SignalLine
    
    
    // MACD- Background Color Change Condition
    
    MACDHistogramCross = MACDHistogram > 0 ? 1 : 0
    
    MACDLineOverZero = MACDLine > 0 ? 1 : 0
    
    MACDLineOverZeroandHistogramCross = MACDHistogramCross and MACDLineOverZero ? 1 : 0
    
    MACDLineUnderZeroandHistogramCross = not MACDHistogramCross and not MACDLineOverZero ? 1 : 0
    
    
    // Fast MACD Calculations
    
    FastMACDfastMA = 8
    FastMACDslowMA = 21
    FastMACDsignalSmooth = 5
    
    
    FastMACDLine = ta.ema(vclose, FastMACDfastMA) - ta.ema(vclose, FastMACDslowMA)
    
    FastSignalLine = ta.ema(FastMACDLine, FastMACDsignalSmooth)
    
    FastMACDHistogram = FastMACDLine - FastSignalLine
    
    // Fast MACD- Background Color Change Condition
    
    FastMACDHistogramCross = FastMACDHistogram > 0 ? 1 : 0
    
    FastMACDLineOverZero = FastMACDLine > 0 ? 1 : 0
    
    FastMACDLineOverZeroandHistogramCross = FastMACDHistogramCross and FastMACDLineOverZero ? 1 : 0
    
    FastMACDLineUnderZeroandHistogramCross = not FastMACDHistogramCross and not FastMACDLineOverZero ? 1 : 0
    
    
    // Top Dog Trading - Mom Dad Calculations
    
    TopDog_Fast_MA = 5
    TopDog_Slow_MA = 20
    TopDog_Sig = 30
    
    
    TopDogMom = ta.ema(vclose, TopDog_Fast_MA) - ta.ema(vclose, TopDog_Slow_MA)
    
    TopDogDad = ta.ema(TopDogMom, TopDog_Sig)
    
    // Top Dog Dad - Background Color Change Condition
    
    TopDogDadDirection = TopDogDad > TopDogDad[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    TopDogMomOverDad = TopDogMom > TopDogDad ? 1 : 0
    
    TopDogMomOverZero = TopDogMom > 0 ? 1 : 0
    
    TopDogDadDirectandMomOverZero = TopDogDadDirection and TopDogMomOverZero ? 1 : 0
    
    TopDogDadDirectandMomUnderZero = not TopDogDadDirection and not TopDogMomOverZero ? 1 : 0
    
    
    
    ////// Trend Barmeter Calculations //////
    
    // UCS_Trend / Trend Candles Trend Barmeter Calculations
    
    //UCS_Trend by ucsgears copy Trend Candles
    //Interpretation of TTM Trend bars. It is really _close to the actual. 
    
    
    haopen = 0.0
    haopen := na(haopen[1]) ? (vOpen + vclose) / 2 : (haopen[1] + vohlc4[1]) / 2
    //hahigh = math.max(high, math.max(haopen, vohlc4))
    //halow = math.min(low, math.min(haopen, vohlc4))
    
    ccolor = vohlc4 - haopen > 0 ? 1 : 0
    
    inside6 = haopen <= math.max(haopen[6], vohlc4[6]) and haopen >= math.min(haopen[6], vohlc4[6]) and 
      vohlc4 <= math.max(haopen[6], vohlc4[6]) and vohlc4 >= math.min(haopen[6], vohlc4[6]) ? 
      1 : 0
    
    inside5 = haopen <= math.max(haopen[5], vohlc4[5]) and haopen >= math.min(haopen[5], vohlc4[5]) and 
      vohlc4 <= math.max(haopen[5], vohlc4[5]) and vohlc4 >= math.min(haopen[5], vohlc4[5]) ? 
      1 : 0
    
    inside4 = haopen <= math.max(haopen[4], vohlc4[4]) and haopen >= math.min(haopen[4], vohlc4[4]) and 
      vohlc4 <= math.max(haopen[4], vohlc4[4]) and vohlc4 >= math.min(haopen[4], vohlc4[4]) ? 
      1 : 0
    
    inside3 = haopen <= math.max(haopen[3], vohlc4[3]) and haopen >= math.min(haopen[3], vohlc4[3]) and 
      vohlc4 <= math.max(haopen[3], vohlc4[3]) and vohlc4 >= math.min(haopen[3], vohlc4[3]) ? 
      1 : 0
    
    inside2 = haopen <= math.max(haopen[2], vohlc4[2]) and haopen >= math.min(haopen[2], vohlc4[2]) and 
      vohlc4 <= math.max(haopen[2], vohlc4[2]) and vohlc4 >= math.min(haopen[2], vohlc4[2]) ? 
      1 : 0
    
    inside1 = haopen <= math.max(haopen[1], vohlc4[1]) and haopen >= math.min(haopen[1], vohlc4[1]) and 
      vohlc4 <= math.max(haopen[1], vohlc4[1]) and vohlc4 >= math.min(haopen[1], vohlc4[1]) ? 
      1 : 0
    
    
    colorvalue = inside6 ? ccolor[6] : inside5 ? ccolor[5] : inside4 ? ccolor[4] : 
      inside3 ? ccolor[3] : inside2 ? ccolor[2] : inside1 ? ccolor[1] : ccolor
    
    TrendBarTrend_Candle_Color = colorvalue ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarTrend_Candle = colorvalue ? 1 : 0
    
    
    // barcolor(Trend_Candle_Color , title = "Trend Candles")
    // barcolor(ShowTrendCandles? Trend_Candle_Color : na, title = "Trend Candles")
    
    
    // RSI 5 Trend Barmeter Calculations
    
    RSI5 = ta.rsi(vclose, 5)
    
    RSI5Above50 = RSI5 > 50 ? 1 : 0
    
    RSI5Color = RSI5Above50 ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarRSI5Color = RSI5Above50 ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    
    // RSI 5 Trend Barmeter Calculations
    
    RSI13 = ta.rsi(vclose, 13)
    
    
    // Linear Regression Calculation For RSI Signal Line
    
    SignalLineLength1 = 21
    
    x = bar_index
    y = RSI13
    x_ = ta.sma(x, SignalLineLength1)
    y_ = ta.sma(y, SignalLineLength1)
    mx = ta.stdev(x, SignalLineLength1)
    my = ta.stdev(y, SignalLineLength1)
    c = ta.correlation(x, y, SignalLineLength1)
    slope = c * (my / mx)
    inter = y_ - slope * x_
    LinReg1 = x * slope + inter
    
    
    RSISigDirection = LinReg1 > LinReg1[1] ? 1 : 0
    
    RSISigCross = RSI13 > LinReg1 ? 1 : 0
    
    RSI13Above50 = RSI13 > 50 ? 1 : 0
    
    
    // Trend Barmeter Color Calculation
    
    RSI13Color = RSI13Above50 ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarRSI13Color = RSI13Above50 ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarRSISigCrossColor = RSISigCross ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarMACDColor = MACDHistogramCross ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarFastMACDColor = FastMACDHistogramCross ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarMACrossColor = MACrossover1 ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarMomOverDadColor = TopDogMomOverDad ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    TrendBarDadDirectionColor = TopDogDadDirection ? #288a75 : color.red
    
    
    TrendBar1Result = TrendBar1 == "MA Crossover" ? MACrossover1 : 
      TrendBar1 == "MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" ? MACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar1 == "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5" ? FastMACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar1 == "Mom Dad Cross (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogMomOverDad : 
      TrendBar1 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogDadDirection : 
      TrendBar1 == "RSI Signal Line Cross - RSI 13, Sig 21" ? RSISigCross : 
      TrendBar1 == "RSI 5: > or < 50" ? RSI5Above50 : 
      TrendBar1 == "RSI 13: > or < 50" ? RSI13Above50 : 
      TrendBar1 == "Trend Candles" ? TrendBarTrend_Candle : na
    
    TrendBar2Result = TrendBar2 == "MA Crossover" ? MACrossover1 : 
      TrendBar2 == "MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" ? MACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar2 == "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5" ? FastMACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar2 == "Mom Dad Cross (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogMomOverDad : 
      TrendBar2 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogDadDirection : 
      TrendBar2 == "RSI Signal Line Cross - RSI 13, Sig 21" ? RSISigCross : 
      TrendBar2 == "RSI 5: > or < 50" ? RSI5Above50 : 
      TrendBar2 == "RSI 13: > or < 50" ? RSI13Above50 : 
      TrendBar2 == "Trend Candles" ? TrendBarTrend_Candle : na
    
    TrendBar3Result = TrendBar3 == "MA Crossover" ? MACrossover1 : 
      TrendBar3 == "MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" ? MACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar3 == "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5" ? FastMACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar3 == "Mom Dad Cross (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogMomOverDad : 
      TrendBar3 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogDadDirection : 
      TrendBar3 == "RSI Signal Line Cross - RSI 13, Sig 21" ? RSISigCross : 
      TrendBar3 == "RSI 5: > or < 50" ? RSI5Above50 : 
      TrendBar3 == "RSI 13: > or < 50" ? RSI13Above50 : 
      TrendBar3 == "Trend Candles" ? TrendBarTrend_Candle : na
    
    
    TrendBars2Positive = TrendBar1Result and TrendBar2Result or TrendBar1Result and TrendBar3Result or 
      TrendBar2Result and TrendBar3Result ? 1 : 0
    
    TrendBars2Negative = not TrendBar1Result and not TrendBar2Result or 
      not TrendBar1Result and not TrendBar3Result or 
      not TrendBar2Result and not TrendBar3Result ? 1 : 0
    
    
    TrendBars3Positive = TrendBar1Result and TrendBar2Result and TrendBar3Result ? 1 : 0
    
    TrendBars3Negative = not TrendBar1Result and not TrendBar2Result and not TrendBar3Result ? 1 : 0
    
    
    FilterXUp = FastMACDHistogramCross and ta.ema(vclose, 15) > ta.ema(vclose, 15)[1]
    
    FilterXDown = not FastMACDHistogramCross and ta.ema(vclose, 15) < ta.ema(vclose, 15)[1]
    
    
    
    TrendFilterPlus = ta.ema(vclose, 15) > ta.ema(vclose, 20) and ta.ema(vclose, 20) > ta.ema(vclose, 30) and 
      ta.ema(vclose, 30) > ta.ema(vclose, 40) and ta.ema(vclose, 40) > ta.ema(vclose, 50) ? 1 : 0
    
    TrendFilterMinus = ta.ema(vclose, 15) < ta.ema(vclose, 20) and ta.ema(vclose, 20) < ta.ema(vclose, 30) and 
      ta.ema(vclose, 30) < ta.ema(vclose, 40) and ta.ema(vclose, 40) < ta.ema(vclose, 50) ? 1 : 0
    
    
    // // Wave Trend - Conditions
    
    // WTCross      = cross(wt1, wt2)
    // WTCrossUp    = wt2 - wt1 <= 0
    // WTCrossDown  = wt2 - wt1 >= 0
    // WTOverSold   = wt2 <= osLevel2
    // WTOverBought = wt2 >= obLevel2
    
    
    MSBar1PositiveWaveTrendSignal = MSBar1 == "Filter X" ? FilterXUp and WTCross and WTCrossUp : 
      MSBar1 == "Trend Filter" ? TrendFilterPlus and WTCross and WTCrossUp : 
      MSBar1 == "Filter X + Trend Filter" ? 
      FilterXUp and TrendFilterPlus and WTCross and WTCrossUp : WTCross and WTCrossUp
    MSBar1NegativeWaveTrendSignal = MSBar1 == "Filter X" ? FilterXDown and WTCross and WTCrossDown : 
      MSBar1 == "Trend Filter" ? TrendFilterMinus and WTCross and WTCrossDown : 
      MSBar1 == "Filter X + Trend Filter" ? 
      FilterXDown and TrendFilterMinus and WTCross and WTCrossDown : 
      WTCross and WTCrossDown
    
    MSBar2PositiveWaveTrendSignal = MSBar2 == "Filter X" ? FilterXUp and WTCross and WTCrossUp : 
      MSBar2 == "Trend Filter" ? TrendFilterPlus and WTCross and WTCrossUp : 
      MSBar2 == "Filter X + Trend Filter" ? 
      FilterXUp and TrendFilterPlus and WTCross and WTCrossUp : WTCross and WTCrossUp
    MSBar2NegativeWaveTrendSignal = MSBar2 == "Filter X" ? FilterXDown and WTCross and WTCrossDown : 
      MSBar2 == "Trend Filter" ? TrendFilterMinus and WTCross and WTCrossDown : 
      MSBar2 == "Filter X + Trend Filter" ? 
      FilterXDown and TrendFilterMinus and WTCross and WTCrossDown : 
      WTCross and WTCrossDown
    
    
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    BackgroundColorChangePositive = TrendBars3Positive and not TrendBars3Positive[1]
    BackgroundColorChangeNegative = TrendBars3Negative and not TrendBars3Negative[1]
    
    // Signals Color Calculations
    
    MSBar1Color = MSBar1PositiveWaveTrendSignal ? #288a75 : 
      MSBar1NegativeWaveTrendSignal ? color.red : na
    
    MSBar2Color = BackgroundColorChangePositive ? #288a75 : 
      BackgroundColorChangeNegative ? color.red : na
    
    
    // Trend Barmeter Color Assignments
    
    TrendBar1Color = TrendBar1 == "N/A" ? na : 
      TrendBar1 == "MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" ? TrendBarMACDColor : 
      TrendBar1 == "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5" ? TrendBarFastMACDColor : 
      TrendBar1 == "Mom Dad Cross (Top Dog Trading)" ? TrendBarMomOverDadColor : 
      TrendBar1 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TrendBarDadDirectionColor : 
      TrendBar1 == "RSI Signal Line Cross - RSI 13, Sig 21" ? TrendBarRSISigCrossColor : 
      TrendBar1 == "RSI 5: > or < 50" ? TrendBarRSI5Color : 
      TrendBar1 == "RSI 13: > or < 50" ? TrendBarRSI13Color : 
      TrendBar1 == "Trend Candles" ? TrendBarTrend_Candle_Color : 
      TrendBar1 == "MA Crossover" ? TrendBarMACrossColor : na
    
    TrendBar2Color = TrendBar2 == "N/A" ? na : 
      TrendBar2 == "MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" ? TrendBarMACDColor : 
      TrendBar2 == "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5" ? TrendBarFastMACDColor : 
      TrendBar2 == "Mom Dad Cross (Top Dog Trading)" ? TrendBarMomOverDadColor : 
      TrendBar2 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TrendBarDadDirectionColor : 
      TrendBar2 == "RSI Signal Line Cross - RSI 13, Sig 21" ? TrendBarRSISigCrossColor : 
      TrendBar2 == "RSI 5: > or < 50" ? TrendBarRSI5Color : 
      TrendBar2 == "RSI 13: > or < 50" ? TrendBarRSI13Color : 
      TrendBar2 == "Trend Candles" ? TrendBarTrend_Candle_Color : 
      TrendBar2 == "MA Crossover" ? TrendBarMACrossColor : na
    
    TrendBar3Color = TrendBar3 == "N/A" ? na : 
      TrendBar3 == "MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" ? TrendBarMACDColor : 
      TrendBar3 == "MACD Crossover - Fast - 8, 21, 5" ? TrendBarFastMACDColor : 
      TrendBar3 == "Mom Dad Cross (Top Dog Trading)" ? TrendBarMomOverDadColor : 
      TrendBar3 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TrendBarDadDirectionColor : 
      TrendBar3 == "RSI Signal Line Cross - RSI 13, Sig 21" ? TrendBarRSISigCrossColor : 
      TrendBar3 == "RSI 5: > or < 50" ? TrendBarRSI5Color : 
      TrendBar3 == "RSI 13: > or < 50" ? TrendBarRSI13Color : 
      TrendBar3 == "Trend Candles" ? TrendBarTrend_Candle_Color : 
      TrendBar3 == "MA Crossover" ? TrendBarMACrossColor : na
    
    
    CrossoverType2 = TrendBar4 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogDadDirection : 
      TrendBar4 == "MACD Crossover" ? MACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar4 == "MA Direction - Fast MA - TB1" ? MA1Direction : 
      TrendBar4 == "MA Direction - Slow MA - TB1" ? MA2Direction : MACrossover1
    
    color_1 = color.green
    color_2 = color.red
    TrendBar4Color1 = TrendBar4 == "N/A" ? na : CrossoverType2 ? color_1 : color_2
    
    // TrendBar4Color2   = TrendBar4=="N/A" ?     na : TrendBar4=="DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" and TopDogDadDirectandMomOverZero ? color(green, 70) : TrendBar4=="DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" and TopDogDadDirectandMomUnderZero ? color(red, 70) : TrendBar4=="MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" and MACDLineOverZeroandHistogramCross ? color(green, 70) : TrendBar4=="MACD Crossover - 12, 26, 9" and MACDLineUnderZeroandHistogramCross ? color(red, 70) : TrendBar4=="MA Crossover" and CrossoverType2 ? color(green, 40) : TrendBar4=="MA Crossover" and not CrossoverType2 ? color(red, 40) : TrendBar4=="MA Direction - Fast MA" and CrossoverType2 ? color(green, 40) : TrendBar4=="MA Direction - Fast MA" and not CrossoverType2 ? color(red, 40) : na
    
    
    CrossoverType3 = TrendBar5 == "DAD Direction (Top Dog Trading)" ? TopDogDadDirection : 
      TrendBar5 == "MACD Crossover" ? MACDHistogramCross : 
      TrendBar5 == "MA Direction - Fast MA - TB2" ? MA3Direction : 
      TrendBar5 == "MA Direction - Slow MA - TB2" ? MA4Direction : MACrossover2
    
    color_3 = color.green
    color_4 = color.red
    TrendBar5Color1 = TrendBar5 == "N/A" ? na : CrossoverType3 ? color_3 : color_4
    
    
    trenbar1color = ShowTrendBar and not(TrendBar5 == "N/A") ? TrendBar4Color1 : na
    trenbar2color = ShowTrendBar and not(TrendBar4 == "N/A") ? TrendBar5Color1 : na
    
    [trenbar1color, trenbar2color]
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I experienced this error as well in a version 5 Pine library script.

The compiler did not accept one of the function parameters as long as I did not use it in the last statement (=return) although I was using the parameter in other places of the logic.

In a test function I was playing around, I found, that it is not sufficient to use a parameter in variable calculation within the function, you have to use this variable in other places of the function as well.

I tricked the compiler by adding a pseudo return in the last statement of the function:

```
returnValue = true ? <your return value always used> : <dummy calculation with all parameters never used>
```

This made it compile, but generated a warning about a variable.

> Shadowing variable xY which exists in parent scope. Did you want to use the ':=' operator instead of '=' ?

And this was the mistake, I did not use := to assign a new value to an existing variable.

***Wrong code:***

```
var bool xY = false // variable initialization
if (1+3 == 4)
    xY = true //this lets Pine think, you declare a new variable
```

Since I declared a new local scope variable by using =, I did not make use of this local variable in other places of the script - since it is local to a code block.

***Correct code:***

```
var bool xY = false // variable initialization
if (1+3 == 4)
    xY := true //this assigns a new value to the existing variable
```

With the correct code, I did not have to apply the trick above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different ways when hitting this error
I moved the function, I moved the argument, I tried to encapsulate in ?:, I tried to bring the argument into the function scope and pass it through to the calculation it was needed in, I renamed it, I changed its type... I tried a lot of things.

I did find a situation where I could get it to compile. Here's the idea:
Before:

```
targetR2R(float _entryPrice, float _yOffset, float _maxTgtDist, float _stopPrice, float _r2r)
    targetDist     = math.abs(_entryPrice - _stopPrice) * _r2r
    tgtPrice_r2r_S  = _entryPrice - targetDist - _yOffset
    maxDist_S       = _entryPrice - _maxTgtDist
```

After:

```
targetR2R(float _entryPrice, float _yOffset, float _maxTgtDist, float _stopPrice, float _r2r)
    targetDist     = math.abs(_entryPrice - _stopPrice) * _r2r
    tgtPrice_r2r_S  = true ? _entryPrice - targetDist - _yOffset : _maxTgtDist
    maxDist_S       = _entryPrice - _maxTgtDist
```

Basically, the `targetDist` variable is definitely used because it is the return of the function. You use the problem variable in that statement you know will be returned. using `true ? OldCalc : ProblemVariable`

Ultimately that fixed it for me. Clearly a bug in the compiler. But, till it is resolved. Good luck my friends. Hope you didn't lose too many hours trying to get around it.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Edit:
Ok.. Update a couple weeks/months later.
I keep running into this problem and I may have finally figured out a way that ensures that it is considered used while not interrupting anything in the script.

Error:
`Error at 1376:1 Unused argument '_flipPref' in the 'setStopOrder()' function. Ensure that it utilizes all arguments, as the compiler removes variables within the code that do not impact the output and produce no side effects.`

Fix:\

```
if false 
    runmsg = "StringTextStuff" + str.tostring(_flipPref) + 
     " Sometimes Pinescript is hard..."
    runtime.error("SAVE ME!" + runmsg)
```

Basically, you'll want to create an assembled string with the problem variable in there.
From there you add it to the string in a runtime message.

The original idea that finally clicked was that if a function returns void (such as `runtime.error()` but also, more practically `array.*()`, `table.*()`, etc.) then the compiler knows it put something in there, but it doesn't know what for. Thus it considers it automatically utilized. The reality that the `if false` statement can never be true is irrelevant to it.

Man. Hopefully that works for a long time because that error is beyond annoying!  But, dems de breaks. Hopefully this finds its way to the top of google and saved you the trouble it caused the rest of us!